# Which candidate should be installed for libeigen2 and libconfig++ from repository?

Tags: libraries

I need to install libeigen2 and libconfig++ for compilation of a source code but it is lacking. What library cadidates need to be intalled, -dev dbg or such ?

Answer (score 0):

Source code is, if available, by convention packaged as `<package name>-dev`, short for *development*.